# PS4 LAN party Online

Tags: ps4, psn, battlefield-1, fifa-17

Last weekend we've tried to have a LAN party with some friends all with PS4's, in total 6 PS4's.
We tried to play FIFA 17 profclub and Battlefield 1 online.

But when trying to play online a few PS4's could connect to the Fifa servers and Battlefield servers, just two PS4's did not get any connection with the servers.

All PS4's where connected via working cables, all the PS4's could connect to PSN, but only when try to join an online server, the server connection failed.

There was an cable internet connection 150/15mbps, so I guess there is bandwidth enough.

Now I'm wondering is there something I forgot or need to know about having a LAN party with multiple Playstation 4's?

Comment: 15Mbps is actually not a lot for 6 machines, for upload speed, but it's also possibly that BF1s servers have a limit as to how many times the same IP address can connect to their server.  As you are all connected through the same external IP, that's basically saturating any limit they might have in-place.  Keep in mind that this is speculative, though, because I do not know if there is any such limit.  (Did you try to connect with those machines individually, or did they only fail when all 6 tried?)